# How can I modify the makefile to get more info?

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, compiler-errors, nios

I am running Eclipse for the Altera Nios II processor.

The problem started when I tried to split a code which was working into `.h` and `.c`-files.

I get this message with no other information

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [C_eng_job.elf] Error 1   C_eng_job           C/C++ Problem
```

Looking at the build log, I don't get how to tackle this.
the buildlog is [here](https://github.com/karagiannis/C_eng_job2/blob/master/C_eng_job.build.log)

How should I proceed? It is working when all code is just in one file.

Comment: The build log seems to be very clear about which lines have errors on them.

Comment: it seems that: 1) you did not build a unique project but tried to reuse the default `helloWorld` project..   2) When breaking a project into multiple files, there should be a header file created for each source file.  The header file should describe the contents of the associated source file, that any other source file needs to know.  (mostly this means the header file should contain function prototypes and data definitions (not code and not data declarations).  Then when some source file needs the information in another source file, it `#include`s the related header file.

Comment: @merlin2011
I have no compilation errors, except of this last .elf Error.
Nothing

Comment: A source file needs to `#include` its' own related header file

Comment: That is NOT true, the linked build log shows compile errors in several different files.

Comment: suggest you post all the source code, including any header files that you have written, Then we would be able to help you with specific problems.

Comment: @user3629249 The codemass is too big for posting but is on same repository. These are warnings, not compilation errors. The only error is from the loader I think: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @user3629249 There are no _errors_ in the source files printed in the bild log. There are loads of _warnings_ instead. While I agree that they need to be fixed they are not causing the build to fail. What really makes the build stop seems to be duplicate definition of `font8x8_basic` both in `hello_world.o` and `vga_util.o`

Comment: duplicate definition of `font8x8_basic`.   Suggest either place that definition in only one source file and have that files header file contain a reference, then include that header file in the other source file. --or-- place that definition in a completely separate file and insert a reference in each of the two problem source files

Comment: the question is how to modify the makefile.  BUT you have not posted the makefile, so how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Strongly suggest you add a parameter to you compile statement, similar to: `-Werrors` as an incentive to actually fix the warnings.  Unless your VERY familiar with what is going on with the compiler, always fix all the warnings, before even trying to run the code

Comment: Did you not read the log?  some function called 'close()' is not implemented.  That is a error.   In any case to get any real help, POST THE CODE

Comment: @user3629249 Updated the project structure. Eclipse happens to write into wrong workspace when  two instances of Eclipse running simulatnously with two separted workspaces. Clearly a bug in Eclipse.
Closed everything and started up one single instance of Eclipse in a new workspace. 
Cannot post code because it is an assignment. However the code is availibe for browsing at [here](https://github.com/karagiannis/C_eng_job2)
Code is in ~/HW_C_engjob/HW_C_ingjob/software/C_eng_job4